# Trying to remove punctuation and count words

Tags: c, string, file-io

I am trying to remove all punctuation from a word. The program reads a file then using a hash counts all occurrences of each word. It mostly works. I am running into trouble when I come across this line

```
, , ,  , , , , , ,  . ./  . /   !@#$%^&*()_(&*^%&^%$%$%##%$%$# %%%$  ^%%^ % ^ %^&^ &^ &^ &^&^ &^ &^ &^ &^ %^% ^ % %$ %$ %$
```

My program prints out "`, 32`"

If there were words it would print out

"word, number"

But for this case it prints what Im assuming is an empty string and ive tried for that

Here is my file that does the main stuff.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include"hash.h"

#define SIZE 5000

void fileRead(char * filename);
void fileWrite();
void removep(char * p);
struct listnode * hashTable[9000];

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    int i;
    if(argc<2)
        fprintf(stderr,"Enter filename \n");

    hashCreate(hashTable, SIZE);

    for(i=1; i<argc; i++){
        fileRead(argv[i]);
    }

    fileWrite();
    hashDelete(hashTable, SIZE);
    return 0;
}

void fileWrite(){
    FILE * file=fopen("wordfrequency.txt","w");
    int i;
    struct listnode * temp;
    for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++){
        temp=hashTable[i];
        if(hashTable[i]->count!=0){
            for(temp=hashTable[i]; temp!=NULL; temp=temp->next){
                fprintf(file,"%s, %d\n",temp->word, temp->count);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void fileRead(char * filename){
    FILE * file = fopen(filename,"r");
    char word[500];
    if(!file){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error opening file \n");
        return;
    }
    while(fscanf(file, "%s", word)==1){
        removep(word);
        if(word!=NULL || word[0]!='\0')
            hashAdd(word,hashTable,SIZE);
    }
    fclose(file);
}

void removep(char *p)
{
    char *src = p, *dst = p;

    while (*src)
    {
       if (ispunct((unsigned char)*src))
       {
          src++;
       }
       else if (isupper((unsigned char)*src))
       {
          *dst++ = tolower((unsigned char)*src);
          src++;
       }
       else if (src == dst)
       {
          src++;
          dst++;
       }
       else
       {
          *dst++ = *src++;
       }
    }

    *dst = 0;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, in `fileRead`, `if(word!=NULL || word[0]!='\0')` will *always* be true because `word` will *never* be `NULL`, and thus you always hash and insert. A basic array can never be `NULL`. Arrays aren't pointers. That clause should be `if (*word)`

Comment: Please don't include unused code in your question — it makes it into something other than an MCVE ([MCVE]) since, by definition, the unused code means it is non-minimal.

Comment: I think WhozCraig got to a key line, but the `||` could be `&&` and then things would work better — but you can drop the first clause as WhozCraig said.  Personally, I'd far rather see `if (word[0] != '\0')` than `if (*word)`, but they're equivalent and it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I changed

> if(word!=NULL || word[0]!='\0')

to

> if(word[0]!=' ' && word[0]!='\0')

and now it works perfectly.